# How to stop ubuntu-1 delete sync feature?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I use ubuntu-1. Now last time I accidentally deleted my documents.Unfortunately ubuntu-1 was in sync so the documents got deleted from there too. I don't want this to happen again. So Is there any way such that ubuntu-1 will only sync files, but If I delete in my folder, it will not delete it in the cloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in Ubuntu One site you have possibility to restore deleted files:

As of October 2013, you also have a way to recover them from the server: In your Ubuntu One profile in the web, you can chose the option "Recover deleted files". This will start a job that will recover the deleted files and will place them in a folder called "Recovered" followed by the date of the recovery.

https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/how-can-i-recover-files-deleted-from-my-account/

But there is no possibility to prevent deleting from the cloud.